# What is the bottleneck in SELECT from InnoDB tables?

Tags: mysql, performance, mariadb

For an InnoDB table with 500 million rows (on a separate NVMe drive), `SELECT COUNT(*)` takes about 3 min.

`SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G` shows `ROW OPERATIONS` of about 2M reads/s, which is consistent with the time the query takes.

It also shows `FILE I/O` of about 3,000 reads/s. This is similar to that read from `iostat`, which also shows the read speed of about 50MB/s.

The NVMe has a lot more capability for reading the data from the disk.

I wonder what is the bottleneck here? Is it still `I/O`, or is it MySQL processing?

**EXAMPLE**

I did a basic reproducible test.

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Number int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB

INSERT INTO test (Number) SELECT * FROM seq_1_to_500000000;
Query OK, 500000000 rows affected (20 min 2.846 sec)
Records: 500000000  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test;
+-----------+
| COUNT(*)  |
+-----------+
| 500000000 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (1 min 20.234 sec)
```

After restarting `MySQL`

```
innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup=OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown=OFF
query_cache_type=0
query_cache_size=0
```

in the absence of any other activity, I got

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test;
+-----------+
| COUNT(*)  |
+-----------+
| 500000000 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (1 min 13.245 sec)
```

***The key question:*** Is it the fastest you can run this query on a typical NVMe?

*Configurations:*

- 50GB buffer pool. The `ibd` file is 17.7GB.
- CPU is 16/32 cores/threads.
- `innodb_io_threads` has no effect. I tried 4 (default) and 64 (max).

and

```
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'innodb_buffer_pool%';
+-----------------------------------------+-------------+
| Variable_name                           | Value       |
+-----------------------------------------+-------------+
| Innodb_buffer_pool_dump_status          |             |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_load_status          |             |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_resize_status        |             |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_load_incomplete      | OFF         |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data           | 874527      |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data           | 14328250368 |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty          | 0           |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_dirty          | 0           |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed        | 0           |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free           | 2351473     |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_made_not_young | 0           |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_made_young     | 0           |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc           | 0           |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_old            | 322843      |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total          | 3226000     |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_lru_flushed    | 0           |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_rnd       | 682843      |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead           | 0           |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_evicted   | 0           |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests        | 56901439    |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_reads                | 874396      |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_wait_free            | 0           |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests       | 515         |
+-----------------------------------------+-------------+
23 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

**Additional information about the table**

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'test';
+------+--------+---------+------------+-----------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+-----------------+----------+----------------+---------+------------------+-----------+
| Name | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows      | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time         | Check_time | Collation       | Checksum | Create_options | Comment | Max_index_length | Temporary |
+------+--------+---------+------------+-----------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+-----------------+----------+----------------+---------+------------------+-----------+
| test | InnoDB |      10 | Dynamic    | 499216334 |             25 | 12859736064 |               0 |            0 |   7340032 |      500000001 | 2022-07-29 00:10:49 | 2022-07-29 00:32:52 | NULL       | utf8_general_ci |     NULL |                |         |                0 | N         |
+------+--------+---------+------------+-----------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+-----------------+----------+----------------+---------+------------------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)

EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test;
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| EXPLAIN                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| {
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "table": {
      "table_name": "test",
      "access_type": "index",
      "key": "PRIMARY",
      "key_length": "4",
      "used_key_parts": ["id"],
      "rows": 499216334,
      "filtered": 100,
      "using_index": true
    }
  }
} |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_io%';
+------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name          | Value |
+------------------------+-------+
| innodb_io_capacity     | 32000 |
| innodb_io_capacity_max | 64000 |
+------------------------+-------+
```

Comment: Please tell us more. 1) How much RAM ??? 2) What is innodb_buffer_pool_size ??? 3) What is output of `nproc` ??? 4) What what are the buffer pool metrics (`show global status like 'innodb_buffer_pool%';`) ??? 5) How many IO threads (`show global variables like 'innodb%io%threads';`)

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA, thanks for your kind attention. I updated the question with the required information as you instructed.

Comment: @Googlebot  Have you considered that using innodb_io_capacity at 32000 could lead to early death of the device?   900 might be a more reasonable limit for your device and still be high.y performant.   Max will auto adjust to innodb_io_capacity * 2 on stop/start of instance.

Comment: You may wish to use 
    SELECT COUNT(id) FROM test;;  
to minimize reading to the Primary Index only to count your rows.

Comment: @Googlebot  If you could post complete TEXT results of SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;  we would know what Version you are running and Rolando could determine values of innodb%io%threads and we would know ALL the variables than can affect your server, including innodb_flush_neighbors and various delay variables.

Comment: @WilsonHauck, I don't mind adding that information, but `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES` is 700 rows. On the other hand, I doubt if it can help. If you (or anyone else) can run the example queries (`INSERT` or `SELECT`) faster than mine, then we can compare the configs to find the problem.

Comment: @WilsonHauck, I don't mind the early death of the device. My system is highly write-intensive (solely used for data processing, not a server). The standard lifespan of NVMe will soon be over. On the other hand, I would replace them with new models before they die (my motherboard is PCIe 3.0, and now PCIe 4.0 offers twice the speed). Anyhow, 32000 does not lead to any `I/O` activity that an NVMe cannot handle.

Comment: Probably time to start an entry with ONE Question then you can get one answer - that might be actionable.

Comment: @WilsonHauck, what was the second question here?

Comment: Maybe this is a second question.... 
INSERT was specifically part of my question, as its speed seemed reasonable. However, if one can INSERT the 500-million rows faster than 20min, it can shed light on possible ways to improve the performance of InnoDB.   Maybe not.

Comment: @WilsonHauck, I try to find the bottleneck. If either `INSERT` or `SELECT` can be faster than my benchmark, I can find out what the bottleneck is in my system. I mentioned only `SELECT` in the original question because there are more factors involved in `INSERT`.

Comment: @Googlebot  If you could post the 700 lines of data requested 2022-07-30 13:20 I will offer suggestions to get the best possible INSERTS per second for your instance.

Comment: @WilsonHauck, I am more than happy to provide further information. SE does not allow such a long question: `Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 95417.` If you mention which parameters you are interested in, I can limit the output by `LIKE`.

Comment: Consider posting the TEXT output to justpaste.it and share the link.

Comment: @WilsonHauck, Thanks for following up. Here is the full output https://justpaste.it/9i0ax

Comment: This is output of SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES \G which is not usable - sorry.
SHOW GLOBAL VARAIBLES;  will be usable when posted.  Thanks

Comment: @WilsonHauck, I updated without `\G`. https://justpaste.it/9i0ax it doesn't help. If I paste it into the editor, the browser will crash. If I paste it into HTML, it will remove all tabs.

Comment: Thanks for your magic.  I can use the content posted at this time.  Give me 48 hours to summarize my observations, please.

Comment: @WilsonHauck, thanks for your supportive assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section to minimize bottlenecks

```
Disable server_id with leading # to eliminate all REPL overhead
have_query_cache=0  # from YES to aliminate all QC overhead
innodb_flush_log_at_timeout=20  # from 1 for 20 second flush vs every second
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # from 128 for minimim scan depth
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm-0.001  # from 0% to enable pre-flushing
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct=0.002  # from 0% to tolerate some dirty pages
thread_cache_size=64  # from 8 
read_rnd_buffer_size=32K  # from 1G to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS
read_buffer_size=512K  # from 1G to reduce handler_read_next RPS
innodb_buffer_pool_size=32G  # from ~ 50G - loading less than 20G data/ndx
innodb_change_buffer_max_size=50  # from 0% for higher loading rows RPS
innodb_fast_shutdown=0  # to ensure dirty pages to media before shutdown
innodb_flushing_avg_loops=4  # from 30 to expedite dirty page reduction
innodb_read_io_threads=64  # from 4 per stackexchange Q 5666 Rolando's advice
innodb_write_io-threads=64  # from 4 per 9/12/2011 Rolando's advice
```

There are likely additional opportunities to be considered.

Answer (score 1):

Simple question; not a simple answer.  Bear with me while I ramble on...

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl` will use the "smallest" index.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can discuss specifics.  Also provide `SHOW TABLE STATUS` so we can discuss the sizes.

Given that the chosen `INDEX` is, say 4GB on disk, divide that by 16K to get 256K blocks that need to be read.  Some of the blocks may already be in cache.  Alas, these numbers don't match anything you gave.

Another way to look at the effort is by running this both before and after the SELECT:

```
 SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'InnoDB%';
```

Then subtract the numbers.  Some will be byte counts; some with be block counts.  There is a factor of 16K between the two, it should be obvious to see which is which.  The one in question might be `Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data`.  Do the process a second time; see how that number changes.

So far, I have not addressed your question directly.  Let's see if I can some closer...

- InnoDB uses one main thread for the query.  [Caveat:  the latest version tries to do some parallelism for `COUNT(*)`.]
- It uses a background thread to do the actual I/O, but that does not really matter, because...
- It will read a block, count the rows, then move on to the next block.
- There may be unrelated activity going on at the same time.  For example, if you recently inserted lots of rows, the updating of the secondary indexes may be just now hitting the disk.
- Since the COUNT must read each block into RAM in the buffer_pool, other blocks may need to be bumped out of that cache.  This can lead to disk writes while you are doing an essentially read-only task.
- If you run the query twice, the second time may run a lot faster than the first -- this would be due to the first run filling the cache; the second one not doing any I/O!  But...
- If the index being used is bigger than will fit in cache, *each* run will do lots of I/O reads.
- InnoDB is more designed for doing multiple actions from separate connections "simultaneously".  For example, you might be able to do 10 counts at the 'same time' in, say, 6 seconds.  Which do you care about?  Latency -- 3 sec for a single query versus Throughput -- 10 queries in 6 seconds?
- If those 10 queries are touching the same blocks, then caching avoids lots of I/O.  If they are touching different blocks, then the disk drive may be the bottleneck.

Comment: I provided an example with configuration data to provide a tangible case.

Comment: @Googlebot - Did you restart MariaDB before running that test?  If not, any "counters" in that STATUS list are useless because they count from restart time.

Comment: yes, I restarted MariaDB before the second `SELECT`.

Comment: I got a similar time for COUNT(*) of a large table on my NVMe.  (I have not tried the `INSERT`; was that part of your question?)  Please provide `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'test';` and `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test;`

Comment: `INSERT` was specifically part of my question, as its speed seemed reasonable. However, if one can `INSERT` the 500-million rows faster than 20min, it can shed light on possible ways to improve the performance of `InnoDB`. I added further information as you suggested.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_io%';`

Comment: I have experimented with `innodb_io_capacity` a lot. At the SDD range, it does not limit such a simple `INSERT`, and does not affect `SELECT`. I use a higher value (at least higher than what is recommended), since I write to several NVMe drives, and it helps to avoid filling the buffer pool in large `INSERT`s. I added to the question, anyway.